# How to avoid the error for complex round method.?

Tags: python, rounding

for this code:

```
def area(d, l): 
x=((d**2)-(l**2))**0.5
#b=sqrt(x)
rec_area=float(round(l*x, 2))
if d<=l and d<=x:
    print("'/Not a rectangle'/")
elif l==0.0 and d==0.0:
    print(""'/Not a rectangle'/"")
else:
    return rec_area
pass
print(area(12, 5))
```

I am getting error:

```
type complex doesn't define __round__ method
```

How to solve it.How can I solve this problem.I am trying to get area and there will be upto two decimal places.I also want to Find the area of a rectangle when provided with one diagonal and one side of the rectangle. If the input diagonal is less than or equal to the length of the side, return "Not a rectangle". If the resultant area has decimals round it to two places.

Pls tell me how to remove none from the output.

Comment: Move your calculation of `x` and `rec_area` inside the `else:` branch. You should also remove `d<=x` from the condition.

Comment: could you pls tell me how to remove 'none' from the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get 'none' in case when the diagonal is smaller then a side, then your function prints "Not a rectangle" and returns 'none' to the main function. There are two ways to deal with that: you can either always print the result inside your function and not use the print in the calling code, or you can return a string from your function and print it in the main code.
Solution 1:

```
def area(d, l): 
    if d<=l or l == 0.0:
        print("'/Not a rectangle'/")
    else:
        x=((d**2)-(l**2))**0.5
        rec_area=float(round(l*x, 2))
        print(rec_area)

area(12, 5)
```

Solution 2:

```
def area(d, l): 
    if d<=l or l == 0.0:
        return "'/Not a rectangle'/"
    else:
        x=((d**2)-(l**2))**0.5
        rec_area=float(round(l*x, 2))
        return rec_area

print(area(12, 5))
```